# How to check the number with Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex

My code takes a photo and converts it to a string and then needs to check if the number is in the photo.

For example, from the photo that I convert to string, I want to check if the number "5545621548956254" is in the photo>>string.
I want to use Regular Expressions (or do suggest any better ideas) and check if the first 4 numbers: "5545" is in the code print of the whole number. But I'm having problems doing that.

Below is the code.

```
import re
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

hand = image_to_string(Image.open("new1.png"))
m = re.search(r'5545', hand)
if m:
   print ("the line: ", m.group(0))
else:
   print "nope"
```

Comment: I guess it returns `"nope"`? Do you know for sure `hand` contains that string? Have you tried: `if '5545' in hand: #do stuff` ?

Comment: Does changing `m.group(0)` to `hand` solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if else in regex but since default re-module in python doesn't support this functionality so you have to install [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) :

pip install regex

then

```
import regex
text="""5545621548956254

554511111111111111


55234566
55451111111111111111111

43333"""
pattern=r'(?(?=^5545)\d+|\s)'




print(list(filter(lambda x:x!='\n',regex.findall(pattern,text,regex.MULTILINE))))
```

output:

```
['5545621548956254', '554511111111111111', '55451111111111111111111']
```

regex info:

```
If Clause (?(?=(^5545))\w+|\s)
Evaluate the condition below and proceed accordingly
Positive Lookahead (?=(^5545))
Assert that the Regex below matches
1st Capturing Group (^5545)
^ asserts position at start of a line
5545 matches the characters 5545 literally (case sensitive)
If condition is met, match the following regex \w+
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Else match the following regex \s
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
if re.match(r'^5545', hand):
    print(hand)
```

The ^ means the beginning of the line.